# Can I add officials debian repository to kali 2.0 source list

Tags: debian, kali-linux, repository

Can I add the following debian wheezy repository to kali 2.0 source list or will it hurt my system? Because I know kali was built on debian wheezy.

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Doesn't Kali 2.0 get its packages from testing? I don't think adding a repository for wheezy (=oldstable) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kali Linux 2.0 is based on Jessie and is, from now on, a rolling release, where they pull packages from Debian testing.

This makes it a complicated situation. It could (!) work for now flawlessly to use jessie sources beside but you will probably run into situations where you get problems with broken packages.

You could work around these problems by using the appropriate sources for your needs and keep the impact minimal by pinning carefully.

Comment: So if I use Jessie repository I SHOULD be fine?

Comment: Try it, definitely not impossible to work, but probably some problems (depends on repository usage).

Comment: No, don't use `jessie`, that's the current stable release.  You want to specify `testing`, not `jessie` or `stretch` (the current testing) so that you remain locked on testing.  Otherwise, when Debian [releases](https://www.debian.org/releases/) `stretch` and creates a new `testing` repository, you'll find things break.